# TAniIndicator not spinning - loading a tlistview

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm new with the TAniindicator component, so for testing purposes I have put together a project that will build a listview and display/spin the Aniindicator whilst the listview is being built.

```
type
TLoadThread = class(TThread)
public
 constructor Create; reintroduce;
protected
 procedure Process;
 procedure Execute; override;
end;    

constructor TLoadThread.Create;
begin
 inherited Create(True);
 FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

procedure TLoadThread.Process;
begin
 Form1.BuildListView;
end;

procedure TLoadThread.Execute;
begin
 inherited;
 FreeOnTerminate := True;
 Synchronize(Process);
end;

var _loadThread : TLoadThread;

procedure TForm1.ThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
begin  
 AniIndicator1.Enabled := False;
 AniIndicator1.Visible := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.BuildListView;
var i : integer;
    LI : TListViewItem;
 begin
  Listview1.BeginUpdate;
 try
  for i := 1 to 2000 do
  begin
   LI := Listview1.Items.Add;
   LI.Text := 'Listview Item ' + IntToStr(i);
  end;
 finally
  Listview1.EndUpdate;
 end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 AniIndicator1.Visible := False;
 _loadThread := nil;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 _loadThread := TLoadThread.Create;
 _loadThread.OnTerminate := ThreadTerminated;
 _loadThread.Start;
 AniIndicator1.Enabled := True;
end;
```

I thought I was on the right track but this doesn't appear to work, can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your worker thread is spending all of its time inside of its `Process()` method, which is being called by `TThread.Synchronize()` so it runs in the main UI thread. `Process()` is not processing UI messages, which is why `TAniIndicator` does not work.

As-is, your worker thread is completely useless. All of your code is running in the main UI thread.  So, you may as well get rid of `TLoadThread` altogether:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AniIndicator1.Visible := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.BuildListView;
var
  i : integer;
  LI : TListViewItem;
begin
  AniIndicator1.Visible := True;
  AniIndicator1.Enabled := True;
  ListView1.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for i := 1 to 2000 do
    begin
      LI := ListView1.Items.Add;
      LI.Text := 'ListView Item ' + IntToStr(i);
      if (i mod 100) = 0 then
        Application.ProcessMessages;
    end;
  finally
    ListView1.EndUpdate;
    AniIndicator1.Enabled := False;
    AniIndicator1.Visible := False;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  BuildListView;
end;
```

Otherwise, if you use a thread, do not synchronize the loop itself, only the pieces that actually touch the UI:

```
type
  TLoadThread = class(TThread)
  public
    constructor Create; reintroduce;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

constructor TLoadThread.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

procedure TLoadThread.Execute;
begin
  Form1.BuildListView;
end;

var
  _loadThread : TLoadThread = nil;

procedure TForm1.ThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
begin
  _loadThread := nil;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AniIndicator1.Visible := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.BuildListView;
var
  i : integer;
begin
  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
   procedure
   begin
     AniIndicator1.Visible := True;
     AniIndicator1.Enabled := True;
     ListView1.BeginUpdate;
   end
  );
  try
    for i := 1 to 2000 do
    begin
      TThread.Synchronize(nil,
        procedure
        var
          LI : TListViewItem;
        begin
          LI := ListView1.Items.Add;
          LI.Text := 'ListView Item ' + IntToStr(i);
        end
      );
    end;
  finally
    TThread.Synchronize(nil,
      procedure
      begin
        ListView1.EndUpdate;
        AniIndicator1.Enabled := False;
        AniIndicator1.Visible := False;
      end
    );
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if _loadThread <> nil then
  begin
    _loadThread := TLoadThread.Create;
    _loadThread.OnTerminate := ThreadTerminated;
    _loadThread.Start;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why AniIndicator doesnt appear , and If I dont do the visible=false; it appear after the whole process finish. By the way I use C++ Builder 10.3.1

Comment: @mesutuk that would imply that the main UI thread is either not processing the `Synchronize()` requests, or the thread is simply finishing its work before the UI is updated.

Comment: Basicly I run a SQL on android and place them into a listview. It does appear when the whole process finish not before. I did try Application->ProcessMessages() but didnt work either. I also tried some other object to make visible but no use. Is there any update command or something to make it visible before the sql process starts.

Comment: @mesutuk I would need to see the actual code. Please post a new question about this.

Comment: Actual code didnt fit into the comments section.. I will ask as a question after some more try.. Note: I dont user Threads.. simply AniIdacator1.Visible= true; AniIdacator1.Enable= true; then execute Sql Query and Application->ProcessMessages() then in while i put records been fetched from sql into a list view and then close the Query and AniIdacator1.Enable= false; AniIdacator1.Visible= false;

Comment: @mesutuk "*Actual code didnt fit into the comments section*" - you shouldn't be posting code in comments to begin with. And you shouldn't be trying to hijack this question with a new issue.  That is why I asked you to post a new question, where it belongs.

Comment: sorry i didn't see you asked me a new post. apologies again.